Cannot connect two container in the same network on GitHub Actions and Docker
I am using GitHub Actions to make the C.I. of project and when I run the container in the same network as the database they don't connect and I get the error: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN 'lightformsdev' .
This is my GitHub Actions .yaml file:
name: Continuous Integration

on:
    push:
        branches: [ main ]

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout code
              uses: actions/checkout@v3

            - name: Setup Node.js
              uses: actions/setup-node@v2
              with:
                  node-version: '18'
                  cache: 'npm'

            - name: Install Yarn
              run: npm install -g yarn
          
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: yarn install
              
            - name: Build
              run: yarn build

    deploy:
        needs: build
        runs-on: self-hosted
        steps:
            - name: Checkout code
              uses: actions/checkout@v3

            - name: Remove existing container
              run: docker rm -f clightformsapi

            - name: Remove existing image
              run: docker image rm ilightformsapi

            - name: Build the new image
              run: docker build -t ilightformsapi -f Dockerfile.main .
                
            - name: Run new container
              run: docker run --net lightformsdevops --name clightformsapi -p 3030:3030 --env-file ~/desenv/.env.prod -d ilightformsapi

            - name: Confirmation
              run: echo ON AIR

It runs, and the status is succeeded but when I do a docker logs -f clightformsapi  the error appears.
I tried to create a new network inside the container, but I get an error always I have to rerun the action.
My network when I inspect it is:
[
    {
        "Name": "lightformsdevops",
        "Id": "fcb6b2d921bd77c8a493530909f920ea7fe3da12728578a005aacce972ffd42b",
        "Created": "2024-04-08T23:03:59.655350666Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "708879215a2a9b02e8cd0fb20b9b1d6c8c4d8984dd4cc21f22734e2286e4c88b": {
                "Name": "lightformsdev",
                "EndpointID": "bac3524810ae5b56b50fcefd669c7e2ccaa2aa7c22625dbd54b75bb440358e26",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7b27b0bc6ba509202e81297c4211e3c47d37e4dd75733c0dc1dfeb23f470f349": {
                "Name": "clightformsapi",
                "EndpointID": "0bffa651a751da8d002e25800c6eb44b1a3d0ead4c6cb02d69e3c522278b86b7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]

